# UIAlertview without subtitle?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created an alertview using sclAlertView framework
(code given below)

```
    let appearance = SCLAlertView.SCLAppearance(
        showCircularIcon: false,
         showCloseButton: false
    )

    let alertView = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance)
    alertView.addButton("Lost", backgroundColor: UIColor.whiteColor(), textColor: UIColor.blackColor(), showDurationStatus: false) {
        print("Lost Tapped")
    }

    alertView.addButton("Found", backgroundColor: UIColor.whiteColor(), textColor: UIColor.blackColor(), showDurationStatus: false) {
        print("Found Tapped")
    }

    alertView.showCustom("Please Pick", subTitle: "", color: UIColor.blackColor(), icon: UIImage(named: "about")!)
```

However i want to know if there is a way to create an alert without subtitle as a little space appears between the title and the buttons..

Comment: can you show the screen shot

Comment: isn't it working with `subTitle: ""`

Comment: try in the place `""` of nil

Comment: "" leaves space between title and buttons whereas nil doesn't work

Comment: can show the screen shot

Comment: That's not a UIAlertView, is that from SCLAlertView: https://github.com/dogo/SCLAlertView ? Are you using last version of it?

Comment: You're using title of UIAlertView whereas you're using SCLAlertView in the question :(